# How to install Install php7-development tools and git, clone the latest phpredis, build and install it

Tags: php, git, github, redis

**So I have instructions to do this.**

Install php5-development tools and git, clone the latest phpredis, build and install it.

If you are using php7 you will need the php7 development tools. You will also need to add `-b php7` after git clone and before the github address.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev git -y
git clone https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis
cd phpredis
phpize
./configure
sudo make
make install
```

I got it, but I have moved to php7, can someone tell me how to install php7-development tools and git ?

I am bit confused here what to do.
Installing phpredis so i need php7 dev tools, can anyone provide me with the exact 1st command for php7 dev tools.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev`?

Comment: Your exact linux distribution should be mentioned.